# woocommerce custom loop tags

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to ask if there is a way in wordpress, to recall all the tags used in the various products in woocommerce. The aim is to create a custom loop that allows you to filter the products by tag. I've been trying for days but I can't get over it. Thank you very much for any replies.

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Answer (score 0):

I update the post, maybe it can be useful to someone. I was stubborn in wanting to use a wp query, inside a while loop. However I was able to solve the problem using a foreach. Given the code used, maybe it can be of help to someone.

However at this point, I would like to ask you a question. Would it be possible to remove a specific tag from the loop?

```
$product_tags = get_terms( 'product_tag' ); // woocommerce tags
$html = '<div class="filter-bar__tags-filter">';
foreach ( $product_tags as $tag )
{
    $tag_link = get_tag_link( $tag->term_id );
    $html .= "<a href='{$tag_link}' title='{$tag->name} Tag' class='{$tag->slug}'>{$tag->name}</a>";
    }

$html .= '</div>';
echo $html;
```

Comment: Please start a new question , rather than posing a question in an answer.